# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 6 mismatch the shape on axis 1 afted deploying my own model

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Hello I am trying to build an android image classification project with tflite model to classify chess pieces. I have trained my model and deployed the tflite model as well as the label map in the assets folder in my android project but I get this error:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 6 mismatch the shape on axis 1` .

I have indeed six classes because of the number of the chess pieces. I tried the app with different model and labelmap and the application works. I do not know where I have made mistake. My labelmap does not have empty rows or extra classes. This is the tflite file: https://www.pastefile.com/a44ydg
And this is my labelmap file:
https://www.pastefile.com/9rg9v7
I can provide the whole app if needed, but again this happens only with this model.

P.S. This is the whole error log from android studio: https://pastebin.com/bxdq9x1r

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check the 4 outputs in your model (https://www.pastefile.com/a44ydg) to see if shapes match the 6 labels?

I use `netron` to inspect your [model](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron), but couldn't know shapes of outputs.

You may refer to the [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md) to know what 4 outputs 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess', 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1', 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2', and 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3 are.

Comment: Hello , sorry I am new to this. I read the documentation that you linked me. I have such command that I execute before making the model in tflite format. Do you want to see the command in order to know about those 4 outputs?

Comment: First, maybe you can paste the full call stack of the error message in Java to show more information.

Second, the key is that your output doesn't match the shape. For example, 

the shape is `[1, N]`
but the label map contains `6` rows (where for axis 1: `N != 6`), hence the error will occur.

You can try the inference code in [python](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) to know the output. Typically, `interpreter.get_output_details()` will returns a dictionary with types and shapes, so you can check shapes then.

Comment: I can paste you results from evaluation in tensorboard if that can help you get better picture. I saw that the detection of shapes is not great from the tensorboard. I try now making the steps more and adding more pictures.

Comment: I have added the full error message in my original post.

Comment: This is the command I use for generating the tflite: `command = "tflite_convert \
--saved_model_dir={} \
--output_file={} \
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--allow_custom_ops".format(FROZEN_TFLITE_PATH, TFLITE_MODEL, )`
If you look at input_shapes, I think this is the image shape that the model will know , when i make a picture with my phone I get for example 2000x3000px